# Adicionar campos obrigatórios

Tags: php, javascript, html

Queria saber como faço para colocar que os campos **Nome**, **Email**, **Senha**,do meu formulário sejam obrigatorio preenche-los. Segue meu código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label><br />
                    Nome:
            </label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" />
            <label><br />
                    Sobrenome:
            </label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Segundo Nome" />
            <label><br />
                    Email:
            </label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@hotmail.com.br" />
            <label><br />
                    Senha:
            </label><br />
                    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="********" />
            <label><br />
                    Confirmar Senha:
            </label><br />
            <input type="password" name="csenha" placeholder="********" /><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="button" />

            <input type="reset" name="Redefinir" value="editar"/>
        </form>

        <?php

        //Função para conhecer o nome do botão
         function get_post_action($name)
            {
                $params = func_get_args();

                foreach ($params as $name) {
                    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
                        return $name;
                    }
                }
            }

        //Verifica qual dos botões foi clicado, através do seu nome
        switch (get_post_action('button', 'submit', 'publish')) {
            case 'button':
                // Inclui classes
                include_once './cadastro.php';
                include_once './DAO/Conexao.php';

                //Instanciando Objeto
                $cadastro = new cadastro();
                $conexao  = new Conexao();

                //Buscar valores do formulário
                $nome       = $_POST['nome'];
                $sobrenome  = $_POST['sobrenome'];
                $email      = $_POST['email'];
                $senha      = $_POST['senha'];

                //Setando Objeto (Atribuindo valores ao objeto cadastro)
                $cadastro -> setNome($nome);
                $cadastro -> setSobrenome($sobrenome);
                $cadastro -> setEmail($email);
                $cadastro -> setSenha($senha);






                // Salvar dados
                $conexao ->saveCadastro($cadastro);

                echo "<script>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso! Agora é possível fazer login');</script>";



                break;

            case 'submit':
                //save article and redirect
                break;

            case 'publish':
                //publish article and redirect
                break;

            default:
            //no action sent
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

**jQuery:**

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```

Se está usando HTML5, adicione o atributo `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="nome_do_campo" required>
```

Em `$("input")`, dá pra colocar uma `class` tipo "required" e adicionar nos campos em que desejar deixar obrigatório.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @RuanRodrigues